# Traefik does not seem to request new ACME certificates if traefik.frontend.rule is too long

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, traefik

Setup looks like this: Traefik is started via docker-compose and the backend is another docker-compose project (if this makes any difference). 
The backends docker-compose.yml sets a "traefik.frontend.rule" label that's somewhat lengthy and we had no problem with it until now when more hostnames were added (still <100 SANs - so no LE rate limiting).
I think it could have something to do with the overall length of the label or traefik parsing it incorrectly. If a certain label length is exceeded (somewhere between 2117 and 2140 characters), traefik does not generate new Let's Encrypt certificates on the fly when starting the backend container (acme logging shows nothing but the server configuration reload on ports 80 and 443). Visiting the newly added hostname results in an INTERNAL_SSL_ERROR.

But if traefik itself is restarted, it seems to pick up the changed label and generates a LE request and does not response with an INTERNAL_SSL_ERROR anymore.

How could this be fixed?